# The application has not been granted consent and is unable to be used for local accounts

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I am getting this error when trying to log in using a custom IEF policy with a local account. I have verified that my IEFProxy is set up to access IEFApp and granted consent and that their reply urls are correct. What am missing?

Comment: what docs did you refer to? Could you share here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have faced the same problem while configuring Identity Experience Framework for Azure Active Directory B2C.

The problem was that I missed the step of granting consent on behalf of all users in the tenant (only the global admin can).
For doing that in the legacy flow just go in

> Azure Active Directory > App Registration (Legacy) >
>   ProxyIdentityExperienceFramework > Settings > Required Permissions

and click on `"Grant Permissions"`

In the new flow its:

> Azure Active Directory > App Registration >
>   ProxyIdentityExperienceFramework (it's in the 'All applications' tab) >
>   API permissions

and click on `"Grant admin consent for ..."`.